# JSON.stringify ignores properties in custom class when it is not declared in constructor

Tags: json, angular

I defined a class:

```
export class SavedData{
    public isDone : boolean;
}
```

and try to stringify it:

```
console.log(new SavedData());
```

but it doesn't include the isDone property

```
{}
```

,which I need to move isDone to constructor:

```
export class SavedData{
  constructor(public isDone : boolean){
  }
}
```

to be successful:

```
{"isDone":false}
```

why would it happen? and is it possible to stringify a class property without declaring it into constructor?

Comment: Does it work if you explicitly invoke `JSON.stringify`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working if you initialize it with a default value

```
export class SavedData{
    public isDone : boolean = null; // or = false;
}
```